# Image not found cross sign over jQuery Slideshow in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a jQuery slideshow at http://trulyorganicfoods.com and in IE I am seeing an image overlay on the slider with the cross image sign. I am at a loss to figure out why that is happening, especially with IE not having an inspector.

Is there a decent inspector for IE. Firebug lite doesn't help very mucch.

Can someone please check out why this is happening\?

Answer (score 0):

Install IE9, it have fireBug clone
To remove this cross, add **ALT** attribute to your images (from HTML, not from JS)